# перемещение файлов через ssh с удаленного Ubuntu на локальный Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, файлы, скрипт, перемещение

Мне необходимо, чтобы на локальном ПК запускался скрипт, который бы периодически перемещал файлы с удаленного ПК на локальный ПК. Скрипт будет выполняться через определенное время через cron.
Первоначально я прописал следующий скрипт:

```
scp user@10.10.10.10:/home/user/folder/* /home/localuser/
user@10.10.10.10 'rm /home/user/folder/*'
```

Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что если файлы в папке folder появлялись в процессе копирования, то они не будут скопированы, но будут удалены следующей строкой стрипта.

Такой скрипт у меня не заработал:

```
ssh user@10.10.10.10 'mv user@10.10.10.10:/home/user/* /home/localuser/'
```

Подскажите, как лучше сделать перемещение файлов. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте рассмотреть использование `rsync` для подобной задачи, он умеет скопированные файлы удалять

Comment: `rsync` — хорошая идея... ещё, как вариант, мжно перемещать файлы на удалённом сервере перед копированием во временный каталог... или подготовить список файлов, копировать по списку, а затем удалять конкретно их...

Comment: Благодарю, решил вопрос через rsync -a --remove-source-files